# Regular expression for alphanumeric string, underscore should not be a first or last character

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-2.7

I would like to have a regular expression that checks if a string contains only upper and lowercase letters, numbers, and underscores, but underscore should not be a first or last character in a string for that I am trying with below in Python.

```
"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$"
```

Comment: Will you want to match the empty string, `""` ?

Comment: @user1559873 Please [don't use signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?!_)\w*(?<!_)$
```

`\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

I use negative look ahead `(?!)` to check the first character is not `_`, and negative look-behind `(?<!)` to check the last character is not `_`.

Comment: @thg435: I just blindly follow OP's example (even if OP doesn't know what he/she is doing).

Answer (score 1):

Specify an optional end with your criteria.

```
'^([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9_]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?)?$'
```

The outer parentheses are to permit an empty string, like your original attempt. If you do not wish to match an empty string, you can simplify by removing the beginning parenthesis, and the closing parenthesis with a question mark quantifier.

Also note that I have used capturing parentheses for simplicity; converting the opening parentheses to non-capturing `(?:` will supposedly also make it go a little faster, although in this simple case, it can hardly matter.

As suggested by @JoelCornett, you can use `re.match` to explicitly search only at the start if the string and drop the `^` anchor.

Comment: Um, lower case character? It is correct aside from that, though.

Comment: Hmmm, our answers are looking very similar, and would be practically identical if I made the change you suggested. I believe you posted yours before mine, so I'll go ahead and delete mine and upvote yours.

Comment: I just upvoted yours for the `re.match` suggestion ... I'll add that in.